# How to filter sql query and get average from the data

Tags: mysql

I have a 2 tables below.  I am trying to get the risky shoppers. The risky shoppers are shoppers who have an average risk score of 100.00(rounded to 2 decimal places) or more

This is what I have so far

```
 select m.merchantName,t.hashedShopperReference,  AVG(t.riskScore) as averageRiskScore, COUNT(t.transactionId) as totalNumberofTransactions
from transaction as t
join merchant m on t.merchantId = m.merchantid 
where t.hashedShopperReference IN(select distinct(hashedShopperReference) 
 from transaction where t.merchantId = m.merchantid)
group by t.transactionId
```

which gives me answer

```
Candle Store Inc fe9ac6f772088b00c006ca6736f946a2 10.0000 1
Candle Store Inc e80999e5dbf13cfb9b832fd4618154ca 100.0000 1
Candle Store Inc e80999e5dbf13cfb9b832fd4618154ca 103.0000 1
Local Coffee Roastery LLC e80999e5dbf13cfb9b832fd4618154ca 105.0000 1
Local Coffee Roastery LLC ebc3f4508048e3e673b89d1f963f2e7a 101.0000 1
```

My query shows all the result even those below 100. How can I have my query only show the results above 100

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the query below

```
select m.merchantName,t.hashedShopperReference,  ROUND(AVG(t.riskScore),2) as averageRiskScore, COUNT(t.transactionId) as totalNumberofTransactions
from transaction as t
join merchant m on t.merchantId = m.merchantid 
where t.hashedShopperReference IN(select distinct(hashedShopperReference)
 from transaction where t.merchantId = m.merchantid)
group by t.transactionId
HAVING AVG(t.riskScore) >= 100.0
ORDER BY m.merchantName ASC, averageRiskScore DESC
```

Comment: I get the error `ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 11: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE averageRiskScore >= 100`

Comment: @arriff check if this works

Answer (score 3):

Append `HAVING AVG(t.riskScore) >= 100.0` to the very end of the query you showed us, right after the GROUP BY but before any LIMIT or ORDER BY clause.

Comment: Hi @O.Jones where in the query should I add this?

Comment: At the end, see my edit.

Comment: how can round the average score to 2 decimal places

Answer (score 0):

```
id  name    grocery         price
1   milk    Green Shop      2.34
2   bread   Clark’s Grocery 3.56
3   bread   Super Market    4.15
4   milk    Super Market    1.80
5   bread   Grocery Amanda  2.26
6   milk    Violet Grocery  3.45
7   milk    Clark’s Grocery 2.10
8   bread   Violet Grocery  2.55
9   milk    Grocery Amanda  1.95
```

Let’s find the names of products in which the average price of each product among groceries is higher than 3.00.

```
SELECT name, AVG(price)
FROM product
GROUP BY name
HAVING AVG(price)>3.00;
```